# Automatic imports from imported file

Tags: python, import

I have a file called `utils.py` with the following code:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
```

In another file `test.py` I call the previous one:

```
from utils import *
print np.sqrt(4)
print 1/2
```

Now, as an outcome I get `2` and `0`. That is, `np` imported in `utils.py` also imports to `test.py` through `utils.py`, however the division module does not. Is there a way to make sure division is imported to `test.py` by importing everything from `utils.py`?

The motivation is that in almost all my files I import `utils.py` so I do not want to import division in each file separately, as I can currently do with `np`.

Comment: No, `__future__` imports **must** be at the start of *every module that requires them*; see [`__future__` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future), [relevant PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0236/)

Comment: I have a solution, use python 3

Comment: @no_name: thanks, but that's not an option when you not working alone on the code

Comment: @jonrsharpe: thanks, you can post this as an answer perhaps

Comment: @Ulysses Bakuriu has already done an admirable job!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imports from `__future__` **are not real imports!** They are a [different kind of statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future) that happen to have a similar syntax.

The documentation states clearly:

> It allows use of the new features **on a per-module basis** before the
>   release in which the feature becomes standard.

They are a way to tell python to treat *that file* in a different way, in particular to compile the code using a possibly different syntax or semantics.

So, no you cannot "re-export" `__future__` imports.